# Bookmark points at the wrong page - index page points at cover page

Tags: koma-script, bookmarks, imakeidx

I'm using the KOMA scrbook class with the bookmark package. When inserting a `\hypertaget{}` for the index page, it incorrectly points at the first page of the document, as illustrated in the image below.

I would like to ask two questions:

1. What is wrong with the code example below.
2. Looking at various solution to this problem I often see `clearpage` and `thispagestyle{empty}`, what is the purpose of theses commands?

Thanks
John

[image]

Code example (Compiles with miktex-portable-2.9.6361)

```
\documentclass[twoside=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{bookmark}
\hypersetup
{
    hidelinks, % Remove red boxes
    linkbordercolor=0 1 0,
    colorlinks=false,
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
}

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{
  \texorpdfstring{}{\chaptername\space}\arabic{chapter}
  \texorpdfstring{}{: }
}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{
  \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

%--------------------------------
% 1. Cover (frontmatter)
%--------------------------------

\begingroup
  \hypertarget{Cover}{}
  \bookmark[level=chapter,dest=Cover]{Cover}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw (current page.center) node []{\Huge\centering\bfseries\sffamily\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth}{\centering Lorem ipsum dolor\\[18pt]
    {\Large  Consectetuer adipiscing elit}\\[20pt] 
    {\huge J. Appleseed \& B. Doe}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vfill
\endgroup

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
%--------------------------------
% 2. Copyright (frontmatter)
%--------------------------------
\chapter{Copyright}
Copyright 2017 by Authors\\

\noindent This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported (CC BY-NC-SA 3.0) license. This license is available at\\
\noindent http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% About the Author (frontmatter)
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\chapter{About the Authors}
\textbf{Johnny Appleseed}
\lipsum[30]

\bigskip

\noindent \textbf{Bob Doe}
\lipsum[31]

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Table of contents (frontmatter)
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\hypertarget{tableofcontents}{}
\bookmark[level=chapter,dest=tableofcontents]{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Foreword (frontmatter)
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\chapter{Foreword}
\lipsum[1-3]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Mainmatter
\mainmatter
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}

Nunc sapien\index{Sapien} leo, fringilla\index{Fringilla} ut nulla quis, ornare efficitur libero. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed id mauris et felis commodo scelerisque. Curabitur eu vehicula dolor. Sed facilisis enim magna, a commodo orci auctor fringilla. Praesent egestas lacinia lobortis. Curabitur fermentum eleifend arcu\index{Arcu} sed ornare. Pellentesque semper, lorem id hendrerit luctus, eros urna bibendum sapien, cursus consequat enim nunc vitae urna. Aenean bibendum, libero eget posuere iaculis, tortor ipsum porttitor enim, vitae\index{Vitae} sollicitudin dolor urna at ipsum. Fusce ut rutrum arcu. Praesent luctus sem nisi, ac sagittis\index{Sagittis} nulla lacinia ac. Curabitur ultricies massa a lectus sagittis dignissim. 

\chapter{Sed commodo}
Praesent in laoreet lorem. Pellentesque nec dolor molestie, accumsan justo non, pulvinar odio. Nunc scelerisque urna placerat bibendum molestie. Vivamus mollis\index{Mollis} nec ex in pellentesque. Vivamus sagittis tortor eu dui vulputate, nec tempor massa porttitor. Phasellus convallis nunc vitae\index{Vitae} erat hendrerit, quis rutrum turpis maximus. Mauris pharetra leo eget consectetur sodales. Donec sed justo in enim congue dignissim ac at libero. Vestibulum interdum mattis hendrerit. Nullam interdum, tellus nec ornare scelerisque, sem magna auctor nulla, nec tempus eros risus et sem. Sed iaculis ipsum quis risus porta maximus. In sed quam eu nunc mattis porttitor in id arcu. Fusce vestibulum dolor vestibulum ipsum condimentum, a ullamcorper nisl consequat. Quisque quis elementum leo. 


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Backmatter
% Index must be in arabic numbers
% \backmatter
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\printindex
\hypertarget{Index}{}
\bookmark[level=chapter,dest=Index]{Index}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The hyperanchor is set at the wrong position, that's the cause

Comment: Thanks, changing the order and adding a `\clearpage` solved the problem.

Comment: You should use the `imakeidx` package rather and `\makeindex[columns=1,totoc]` rather, it would work out of the box then. As well, the explicit bookmarks look wrong. Please look into the KOMA documentation with `listof=totoc` in order to prevent the `\bookmark` usages. You also used `[imakeidx]` as a tag here

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Instead of closing the question, wouldn't it be better to add an answer?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Can you make an answer from your comment?

Comment: @Schweinebacke Yes it is also an option :) But I think maybe we could find an duplicate to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[twoside=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=1,intoc]

\usepackage{bookmark}
\hypersetup
{
    hidelinks, % Remove red boxes
    linkbordercolor=0 1 0,
    colorlinks=false,
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
}

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{%
  \texorpdfstring{}{\chaptername\space}\arabic{chapter}%
  \texorpdfstring{}{: }%
}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{%
  \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

%--------------------------------
% 1. Cover (frontmatter)
%--------------------------------

\begingroup
  \hypertarget{Cover}{}
  \bookmark[level=chapter,dest=Cover]{Cover}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw (current page.center) node []{\Huge\centering\bfseries\sffamily\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth}{\centering Lorem ipsum dolor\\[18pt]
    {\Large  Consectetuer adipiscing elit}\\[20pt] 
    {\huge J. Appleseed \& B. Doe}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vfill
\endgroup

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
%--------------------------------
% 2. Copyright (frontmatter)
%--------------------------------
\chapter{Copyright}
Copyright 2017 by Authors\\

\noindent This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported (CC BY-NC-SA 3.0) license. This license is available at\\
\noindent http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% About the Author (frontmatter)
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\chapter{About the Authors}
\textbf{Johnny Appleseed}
\lipsum[30]

\bigskip

\noindent \textbf{Bob Doe}
\lipsum[31]

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Table of contents (frontmatter)
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\hypertarget{tableofcontents}{}
\bookmark[level=chapter,dest=tableofcontents]{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Foreword (frontmatter)
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\chapter{Foreword}
\lipsum[1-3]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Mainmatter
\mainmatter
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}

Nunc sapien\index{Sapien} leo, fringilla\index{Fringilla} ut nulla quis, ornare efficitur libero. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed id mauris et felis commodo scelerisque. Curabitur eu vehicula dolor. Sed facilisis enim magna, a commodo orci auctor fringilla. Praesent egestas lacinia lobortis. Curabitur fermentum eleifend arcu\index{Arcu} sed ornare. Pellentesque semper, lorem id hendrerit luctus, eros urna bibendum sapien, cursus consequat enim nunc vitae urna. Aenean bibendum, libero eget posuere iaculis, tortor ipsum porttitor enim, vitae\index{Vitae} sollicitudin dolor urna at ipsum. Fusce ut rutrum arcu. Praesent luctus sem nisi, ac sagittis\index{Sagittis} nulla lacinia ac. Curabitur ultricies massa a lectus sagittis dignissim. 

\chapter{Sed commodo}
Praesent in laoreet lorem. Pellentesque nec dolor molestie, accumsan justo non, pulvinar odio. Nunc scelerisque urna placerat bibendum molestie. Vivamus mollis\index{Mollis} nec ex in pellentesque. Vivamus sagittis tortor eu dui vulputate, nec tempor massa porttitor. Phasellus convallis nunc vitae\index{Vitae} erat hendrerit, quis rutrum turpis maximus. Mauris pharetra leo eget consectetur sodales. Donec sed justo in enim congue dignissim ac at libero. Vestibulum interdum mattis hendrerit. Nullam interdum, tellus nec ornare scelerisque, sem magna auctor nulla, nec tempus eros risus et sem. Sed iaculis ipsum quis risus porta maximus. In sed quam eu nunc mattis porttitor in id arcu. Fusce vestibulum dolor vestibulum ipsum condimentum, a ullamcorper nisl consequat. Quisque quis elementum leo. 


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Backmatter
% Index must be in arabic numbers
% \backmatter
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\printindex
%\bookmark[level=chapter,dest=Index]{Index}


\end{document}
```